# How can you deprecate old versions of online software documentation in search results?

Tags: seo

If you have multiple supported versions of software documentation online like:

```
https://docs.python.org/2.7/
https://docs.python.org/2.6/
https://docs.python.org/2.5/
```

How can you nudge the search engines to prefer a specific version, such as your latest version, when people search for documentation without creating a `latest` suffix like the following, which could lock you into a documentation page layout to mitigate the risk of breaking links to `latest`:

```
https://docs.python.org/latest/
```